# Difficulty with sending sensor data

Tags: python, python-2.7, arduino

I try to send data over an arduino Ethernet shield to client (python on PC)
the problem that i had is when i read like example the pin A0 in arduino i get 1023 but when i send this value to python i get 49152...

**arduino code**

```
#include <SPI.h>         
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <EthernetUdp.h>

byte mac[] = {  0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };   // Enter a MAC    address for your controller below.
IPAddress ip(192,168,0,101);
IPAddress gateway(192,168,0,254);
IPAddress subnet(255,255,255,0);
unsigned int UDPport = 5000;// local port to listen for UDP packets
IPAddress UDPServer(192,168,0,100); // destination device server

const int UDP_PACKET_SIZE= 48;
byte packetBuffer[ UDP_PACKET_SIZE]; //buffer to hold incoming and outgoing  packets 
unsigned int noChange = 0;
int UDPCount = 0;
EthernetUDP Udp;

unsigned long currentTime;
unsigned long secondTime;
unsigned long msPerSecond = 100UL;

float temperature;
float vitesse;
float charge;
float current;

void setup() 
{
Serial.begin(9600);
Ethernet.begin(mac,ip,gateway,gateway,subnet);
Udp.begin(UDPport);
delay(1500);
currentTime=millis();
secondTime = currentTime;
}



void loop()
{
currentTime = millis();
getUDPpacket();

if(currentTime - secondTime > msPerSecond) {

temperature = analogRead(0); //read analog input on pin A0
vitesse = analogRead(1); //read analog input on pin A1
charge = analogRead(2); //read analog input on pin A2
current = analogRead(3); //read analog input on pin A3
Serial.println(temperature);
sendUDPpacket(UDPServer); // send an NTP packet to a time server
secondTime += msPerSecond;
}
}

unsigned int udpCount = 0;
unsigned long sendUDPpacket(IPAddress& address)
{
udpCount++;
memset(packetBuffer, 0, UDP_PACKET_SIZE);            sprintf((char*)packetBuffer,"%u,%u,%u,%u",temperature,vitesse,charge,current);
Udp.beginPacket(address, UDPport);
Udp.write(packetBuffer,UDP_PACKET_SIZE);
Udp.endPacket(); 
}

void getUDPpacket() {
if ( Udp.parsePacket() ) {  

if(Udp.remoteIP() == UDPServer) {
  Serial.print(F("UDP IP OK  "));
}
else {
  Serial.println(F("UDP IP Bad"));
  return;
}
if(Udp.remotePort() == UDPport) {
  Serial.println(F("Port OK"));
}
else {
Serial.println(F("Port Bad"));
  return;
}

Udp.read(packetBuffer,UDP_PACKET_SIZE);  // read the packet into the buffer
Serial.print(F("Received: "));
Serial.println((char*)packetBuffer);
}
}
```

**the python code**

```
import socket
import time


UDP_IP = "192.168.0.100"
UDP_PORT = 5000


sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                 socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP

sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
data, addr = sock.recvfrom(48)
print data
time.sleep(5)
```

i think the problem is in this line

```
  sprintf((char*)packetBuffer,"%u,%u,%u,%u",temperature,vitesse,charge,current);
```

but i dont know what to do

Comment: "Arduino" is **not** C!

Comment: yes i work with arduino code note C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enable all warnings (eg in gcc use `-Wall`) when you compile your C code. That way, it would warn you when you try to print floats with the `%u` unsigned integer format specifier, as that leads to undefined behaviour.

You should either a) convert `temperature`, `vitesse`, `charge`, and `current`to unsigned integer before passing them to `sprintf()`, or b) change the format specifier to something like `%f` so that `sprintf()` knows to expect floating-point data.

Also you should include `<stdio.h>` so that your program has a prototype for `sprintf()`; I *assume* that those headers you have included contain prototypes & constants relevant to the Ethernet & Arduino port IO functions.